# Counting ten-digit numbers whose digits are all different and that are divisible by $11111$

Tags: combinatorics, algebra-precalculus, number-theory

I've got a problem which I can't finish off and I've been trying for long long time without sucess. I think it's easier than I thought but, maybe yes o maybe not nevertheless I'm trying to do by myself.

The problem says

> Call a number *interesting* if is a $10$-digit number, all of its digits are different and is divisible by $11111$. How many *interesting* numbers are there?

Hitherto, I've tried things like cheking the numbers $\equiv (mod 
 9)$ and $ \equiv (mod 100000) $  and also have checked a base-10 decomposition and I suspecting that there are just 1 or 2 number with the desire properties or there aren't. Should I proced by contradicition? And if I would, any idea?

Comment: HINT: A ten digit number featuring all digits once has a digit sum of $45$ and hence that ten digit number is divisible by $9$. Is $11111$ divisible by $9$?

Comment: There are actually more than 3000 interesting numbers.  The last five are 9874601253, 9875301246, 9875601243, 9876401235, and 9876501234.  Do you see the pattern?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The comments indicate that since $9\nmid11111$ yet the sum of digits of an interesting number is divisible by $45$, all interesting numbers are divisible by $99999$; it is then not hard to show that in such numbers the last five digits are complements ($x\to9-x$) of the first five.

The complementary pairs are $09,18,27,36,45$, so there are $5!\cdot2^5$ ways of assigning pairs to the first five positions of an interesting number and then choosing explicitly the digits that go there – except that $4!\cdot2^4$ must be subtracted for those choices giving a leading zero. This leaves $3456$ interesting numbers.

Comment: Nice. I do notice though, that $3456$ has its on pattern too though. That the number of interesting numbers is itself rather interesting in its own right, well that is pretty interesting too!

Answer (score 1):

Another way to obtain the same is the following. We have to count the number of ways to fill first $5$ digits of the number only, the second half is (digit-wise) complement of it and is uniquely determined by the first half. So in the following $10$-digit number
$$ABCDE - A'B'C'D'E'$$
there are $9$ ways to pick $A$ (excluding $0$), $8$ ways to choose $B$ (since $A$ and $A'$ are filled), $6$ ways for $C$, $4$ for $D$ and $2$ for $E$. Required number is
$$9 \times 8 \times 6 \times 4 \times 2 = 3456$$

Comment: thank your dude. Many ways to learn the same enrich our heads.